# How to hit java.lang.OutOfMemoryError by spawning threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I came across this [blog site](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-what-is-limit-to-number-of-threads.html) where the author is testing against the maximum number of threads before the machine throws a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. However, in my below test codes, i am unable to hit the error despite the arbitrary large threads spawned.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Car());
        thread.setName(Integer.toString(i));
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't amount of threads limited by the OS? AFAIK, on windows one can only create about 2000 threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try sleeping inside the thread, otherwise it might end up too quickly and get garbage collected, as shown in the [example code](http://code.google.com/p/core-java-performance-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/google/code/java/core/threads/MaxThreadsMain.java):

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            //
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: profiling such a program shows that there's plenty of heap and perm gen memory available, but it still throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`. In fact, increasing amount of heap or perm gen memory decreases max amount of thread that can be created, I managed to hit the max of 3231 threads on my machine with `-Xmx5m -XX:MaxPermSize=5m`. So it is no the matter of gc-ing threads, but the limit of the OS.

Comment: for native threads.  there is nothing prohibiting the jvm to use green threads in these cases

Comment: @tulskiy, If you are using a 32-bit JVM, your adressible memory is limited regardless of how much memory you actually have.  The more free address space you have, the more threads you can have. The more memory which is taken up by other things, the less threads you can have. Try reducing the stack size per thread, as suggested in the blog, to get more threads. `-XX:ThreadStackSize=64`

Answer (score 1):

If the (Runnable) `Car` instance exits shortly after being started, the memory allocated for the thread is freed. If the rate of freeing memory is greater than the thread spawning rate, you'll never get an `OutOfMemoryError`. You can prevent that by making `Car` run for a long time, for example:

```
class Car implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
      Thread.sleep(10000000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at the same problem which is covered in the JavaSpecialists Newsletter # 149
http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue149.html

Here is a small piece of code that you can run to find out how many inactive threads you can start on your JVM:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class ThreadCreationTest {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws InterruptedException {
    final AtomicInteger threads_created = new AtomicInteger(0);
    while (true) {
      final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
      new Thread() {
        { start(); }
        public void run() {
          latch.countDown();
          synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("threads created: " +
                threads_created.incrementAndGet());
            try {
              wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
          }
        }
      };
      latch.await();
    }
  }
}
```