# Yet Another Java OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I'm running in 64-bit Windows 7 and Server 2008 with a 64-bit JVM, and I get "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" in a program with plenty of memory available. I have read on and on about garbage collection and heap generations and so forth, but nothing seems to explain this case. The closest I've come is one entry that gave a program that allocates idle threads ([How to hit java.lang.OutOfMemoryError by spawning threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806146/how-to-hit-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-by-spawning-threads) under the Ajay George response) and at least recreates the problem we have in our production code. The problem is that we get the OOM with plenty of OS memory (RAM) available, very little allocated in the heap, and no response to the OOM exception when we run with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError. When running the code above (the idle thread spawner) using a small heap setting (Xmx16M) and a large stack setting (Xss1G) the java process allocates about 8179 threads before failing and has a large commit size when viewed in task manager, but other than that it has claimed very few resources.

I've turned on GC tracing and observed very little activity (usually two GCs) prior to the failure. I've boosted the PermGen to no avail. I boosted the initial heap size to the point where it isn't consumed prior to the failure (Xms1024M Xmx65536M) and it still gets OOM.

I've looked at both of these using the YourKit profiler and it shows exactly what I suspected, which is the heap is not consumed and very few GCs have occurred.

The problem I have in production however only has about 150-300 threads (it varies) when it fails and the stack size is defaulted, so probably 1M in windows.

What I'm trying to find out is how to determine what is causing the problem so I can make appropriate changes to our code.

Is there something special the JVM does when creating threads that has a very limited memory source? I know that with NIO and memory mapped files that the JVM doesn't track the background memory backings and high levels of churning in memory mappings will quickly run out of memory, but in that case the OS shows the use of the memory by the JVM. In our thread case the OS shows the JVM as having a small amount of memory in use.

Comment: You might already have seen this: http://blog.egilh.com/2006/06/2811aspx.html

Comment: How are you creating your threads?

Comment: The test program creates the threads by calling start() in an instance initializer of an anonymous thread instance. @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis

Answer (score 5):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

> What I'm trying to find out is how to determine what is causing the problem so I can make appropriate changes to our code.

You are running out of stack memory and cannot allocate more threads.  It may also be that you are running out of the maximum number of processes allowed by the OS but I'm not sure Windows has such limits.

By default in a 64-bit JVM each thread gets a stack size of 1M and there is a maximum space that the JVM allocates for thread stacks.  You certainly do *not* want to do something like `-Xss1G` which would give each thread a gigabyte.  You might try `-Xss128k` to lower the per-thread memory but this really seems like a bandaid.  See this page: [Adjust Java default thread stack size to save memory](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/209/using-xss-to-adjust-java-default-thread-stack-size-to-save-memory-and-prevent-stackoverflowerror/)

A better way to fix this is to limit the number of threads being created with fixed size thread pools instead of forking a thread for every job.  This depends highly on your architecture.  If you are handling web requests a fixed thread pool will limit the number of concurrent connections but will probably increase your overall throughput.

See the [Thread Pools tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

> The problem is that we get the OOM with plenty of OS memory (RAM) available.

Yeah these are very specific limitations controlled by the JVM.  This is not heap memory and the JVM will not grow to take all memory on the box.

See these links:

- [Thread stack memory vs heap memory](http://www.coderanch.com/t/233050/threads/java/Thread-stack-memory-heap-memory)
- [Difference between Stack and Heap memory in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/01/difference-between-stack-and-heap-java.html)

Comment: All of our threads are in pools already. We're trying to use all of our processors, which is 16 or 32, depending. We allocate threads based on the number of processors and the CPU load of the particular activity.

Comment: Well if you are allocating 100s of threads then something is wrong with that code @WilliamSmith.

Comment: I have run as many as 55,000 threads in my desktop box using the idle thread code referred to in my initial post, so it can't be that we reached an OS thread limit.

Comment: I doubt that you ran that many threads at one time @WilliamSmith.   We are talking about max _concurrent_ threads right?

Comment: I get an error simialr to my production code using the idle threads code iff I run with a relatively small Xmx and a large Xss. In other words, our production code acts like the case where the thread stacks are large, but the memory consumption is low. However the prod code uses the default stack size.

Comment: I think what may be happening is that the `-Xmx` value is used to calculate how much stack space is to be allocated.  I doubt this has anything to do with how much of the heap is used @WilliamSmith.

Comment: If by concurrent you mean "started but not yet exited" then yes. All of them are in a wait state. That is a test program to find the thread limit. In production we allocate normal running threads. @Gray

Comment: And you are running under the same OS and JVM settings @WilliamSmith?

Comment: Xss sets the stack size. Xmx sets the maximum heap size. @Gray

Comment: Same OS. JVM settings are default stack size and Xmx of two-thirds of the RAM. Xms is 1024M and the JVM never allocates more. @Gray

Comment: I know this dude.  There is a 3rd value which is unknown.  What is the total space for all thread stacks?  This is neither Xss nor Xmx.  I suspect that it is a _calculation_ that is made by the JVM _using_ the Xmx number @WilliamSmith.  I bet if you increase the Xmx number you can allocate more threads.  It has _nothing_ to do with how much heap is used.

Comment: In the prod environment I increased the Xmx from 65536M to 92180M and it made no difference. I also reduced the number of threads allocated to various activities and it still gets OOM trying to create a native thread. First time this happend there were 384 threads. Subsequent occurrences were with 120 threads. It's now to the point where the CPUs are not busy. @Gray

Comment: How can this "third" value be discovered? I think that's really my question. @Gray

Comment: If you are hitting this limit at 384 threads @WilliamSmith then there is some other problem.  Either there is a ton more threads that you are not accounting for or you are hitting some per-process thread limit or there are multiple memory issues going on.

Comment: As it turns out, increasing Xmx has no impact on the number of threads that can be created in the idle threads program. Only the stack size affects the number of threads. @Gray